# Why does strlen return a different length for floats?

Tags: php

I do understand that PHP can interchangeably consider a number and string (if it represents a number).

```
<?php
  $original = 23.000000000001;
  echo strlen($original); # Displays 15
?>
```

and thanks to the definite limit a computer can store float values upto,

```
<?php
  $original = 23.0000000000001;
  echo strlen($original); # Displays 2
?>
```

But why does PHP display 3 instead of 15 here?

```
<?php
  $original = 23.0000000000001*10;
  echo strlen($original); # Displays 3
?>
```

Comment: Well as you are trying to get the string length of a floating point number that is NOT a string, I might suggest you are trying to compare Apples and Oranges

Comment: Got it, the answer is simple... `23.0000000000001*10` becomes `230.0000000000001` and due to the same limit I guess PHP can't store values that long internally as well...so 1 gets truncated off, thereby making it 230.

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/3gbYv) might help

Comment: Yup, if you had echo's `$original` that would have led you to that answer

Comment: Yes, I just got the answer when I tried to echo the value of `$original`.  Thanks a lot for the snippet @berend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calculating the length, it is converted to a string. This is the same as

```
echo (string) 23.0000000000001*10; // 230
```

As you can see, the length is really 3
Why is this happening ? Overflow occurs.
during multiplication, the mantisa is transferred, an overflow occurs, the last number does not have enough space

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php

23.0000000000001 ==
0100000000110111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IN IEEE 754 format.
After when multiplying, a byte move to the left is done, as a result, we lose bits

Comment: Yes, that's what I had said in the comments earlier :)